# Error when putting widgets into a frame which is inside a frame. Tkinter - Python3

Tags: python, tkinter

So the code below is a shortened version of what my actual code is. I'm having a problem when getting a widget to appear within a Frame which is placed within a Frame.

So, basically the  code below is a login menu, in which when a button is clicked the frame changes to another frame. In this case `login_frame` to `overview_frame`. Within the `overview_frame` i have a another frame called `titleFrame`, this frame is placed on the `overview_frame`.

Now the problem  occurs when i want to put a widget into the `titleFrame` in this instance the `titleLabel` with the `.grid()` method of placement.

I have done this with other tkinter applications i have created, i've been trying to suss this out for a good few hours now and not come to a conclusion. This is the error i keep getting:

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\nasto\Documents\Company\rfr.py", line 67, in <module>
    app = frame_store()
  File "C:\Users\nasto\Documents\Company\rfr.py", line 16, in __init__
    frame = n_frame(parent=container, controller=self)
  File "C:\Users\nasto\Documents\Company\rfr.py", line 57, in __init__
    titleLabel = tk.Label(titleFrame, text='TITLE').grid(row=0,column=0, sticky='nsew', padx=2, pady=2)
  File "C:\Users\nasto\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2220, in grid_configure
    + self._options(cnf, kw))
_tkinter.TclError: cannot use geometry manager grid inside . which already has slaves managed by pack
```

Now the only difference between this code and the other applications i have made is the `frame_store` class. In which there is one line of code that used `.Pack()` However when removing this the `login_frame` and `titleFrame`do not show and the widget goes directly onto the `overview_frame`. How would i possibly get rid of the `.Pack()` while ensuring that all frames should still be visible, or to place the `titleLabel` on the `titleFrame` while using `.grid()`
I personally think it may be to do with what the `titleFrame` is connected with eg// `self` but while messing around with that i have not been getting the result that works.

```
import tkinter as tk
import hashlib
import sqlite3

class frame_store(tk.Tk):
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    '''container is used so that all the frames can be stacked, from there we can call other frames within the container to the top, to the current active frame'''
    container = tk.Frame(self)
    container.pack(side='top', fill='both', expand=True)
    container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    self.frames = {}
    for n_frame in (login_frame, overview_frame, accounting_frame):
      pageName = n_frame.__name__
      frame = n_frame(parent=container, controller=self)
      self.frames[pageName] = frame
      frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')
    self.show_frames('login_frame')

  def show_frames(self, pageName):
    frame = self.frames[pageName]
    self.update_idletasks()
    self.state('zoomed')
    self.title('A2 Project')
    frame.tkraise()

class login_frame (tk.Frame):
  def __init__(self, parent, controller):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
    self.controller = controller
    loginButton = tk.Button(self, text='Login', command = self.no_credentials).grid(row=3,column=0)
    self.controller.bind('<Control-n>', lambda event: self.no_credentials())

  def no_credentials(self):
    self.controller.show_frames('overview_frame')

  def clear(self):
    self.__userID.set('')
    self.__password.set('')

  def exit(self):
    app.destroy()   


class overview_frame(tk.Frame):
  def __init__(self, parent, controller):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
    self.controller = controller

    self.config(background='#000000')  
    self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

    titleFrame = tk.Frame(self, background='#f8f8ff', bd=1, relief='sunken').grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew', padx=2, pady=2)

    titleLabel = tk.Label(titleFrame, text='TITLE').grid(row=0,column=0, sticky='nsew', padx=2, pady=2)


class accounting_frame(tk.Frame):
  def __init__(self, parent, controller):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
    self.controller = controller
  pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = frame_store()
    app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is due to **creating** your frame and **aligning** it in a single line of code.

When writing:

```
titleFrame = tk.Frame(self, relief='sunken').grid(row=0, column=0)
```

`titleFrame` is the output of the `.grid()` method, instead of the `tk.Frame` you just created. So it cannot be used as a parent for future widgets.

In order to keep the reference to a widget, you have to separate widget creation from widget alignment:

```
titleFrame = tk.Frame(self, background='#f8f8ff', bd=1, relief='sunken')
titleFrame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew', padx=2, pady=2)
titleLabel = tk.Label(titleFrame, text='TITLE')
titleLabel.grid(row=0,column=0, sticky='nsew', padx=2, pady=2)
```