# tkinter interface need assistance

Tags: python, tkinter

I am developing a graphical interface with tkinter. When I open file and send it, I want to see the scrolling instructions in label (Commande)

To be more precise i do not know how to link this instruction `print('Sending: ' + l)` with this instruction `Label(Frame1, text="Commande", background='NavajoWhite2').pack(padx=165, pady=10)`

Thanks to all

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import ttk, Text

#nom de la fenetre

moha = Tk()
moha.title('Emetteur G-code Universel')
moha.geometry("2500x2500")
moha['bg']= 'NavajoWhite2'

##################
##################
#le chemin de recherche #

def file(tk_event=None, *args, **kw):
    fiile = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[('txt files','.txt'),('all files','.*')])
    file_path.set(fiile)
    fichier = open(fiile, "r")
    print(fiile)

    content_bis = fichier.readlines()

    for line in content_bis:
            T.insert(END, line)

    fichier.close()

    # Créer les différentes Frame

    Outil = LabelFrame(moha, text="Outil")
    Outil.place(x=500)
    Outil['bg']= 'NavajoWhite2'
    label = Label(Outil, text='Fichier : ', background='NavajoWhite2')
    label.place(x=10, y=114)

    file_path = StringVar()

    entry = Entry(Outil, textvariable=file_path)
    entry.place(x=60, y=114)
    ################

   def moh():

      # Open grbl serial port
      s = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyS0',115200)

      # Open g-code file

      f = open(file_path.get(), "r");

      # Wake up grbl
      s.write("\r\n\r\n".encode('utf8'))
      time.sleep(2)   # Wait for grbl to initialize 
      s.flushInput()  # Flush startup text in serial input

      # Stream g-code to grbl
      for line in f:
          l = line.strip() # Strip all EOL characters for consistency
          print ('Sending: ' + l)
          s.write((l + '\n').encode("utf8")) # Send g-code block to grbl
          grbl_out = s.readline().decode("utf8") # Wait for grbl response with carriage return
          print (' : ' + grbl_out)

      # Wait here until grbl is finished to close serial port and file.
      raw_input("  Press <Enter> to exit and disable grbl.") 

      # Close file and serial port
      f.close()
      s.close()


    #Créer la barre de recherche 


   #################
  o = LabelFrame(moha, text="Fase des commandes")
  o.place(y=400)
  o['bg']= 'NavajoWhite2'
  Label(o, background='NavajoWhite2').pack(padx=670,pady=120)
  Frame1 = Frame(o, borderwidth=3, relief=GROOVE, background='NavajoWhite2')
  Frame1.place(x=0, y=5)
  Label(Frame1, text="Commande",background='NavajoWhite2').pack(padx=165, pady=10)
  #################
  b1= Button(Outil, text ="Commande", background='White').place(x=10, y=20)
  b2= Button(Outil, text ="Fichier", background='White').place(x=110, y=20)
  b3= Button(Outil, text ="Côntrole de la machine", 
  background='White').place(x=190, y=20)
  b4= Button(Outil, text ="Selectionner un fichier",background='White', 
 command=file).place(x=235, y=112)
  b5= Button(Outil, text ="Envoyer",background='White', command=moh).place(x=30, y=150)
  b6= Button(Outil, text ="Pause",background='White').place(x=110, y=150)
  b7= Button(Outil, text ="Annuler",background='White').place(x=180, y=150)
  Label(Outil, text="", background='NavajoWhite2').pack(padx=300, pady=150)
  ################
  ################
  S = Scrollbar(Outil, background='NavajoWhite2')
  T = Text(Outil, height=19, width=28)
  S.place(x=380, y=10)
  T.place(x=400, y=0)
  S.config(command=T.yview)
  T.config(yscrollcommand=S.set)
```

Comment: You can update the text or any attribute of the Label with the `config` method: `label.config(text='Sending: ' + l)`.

Comment: @Novel I didn't understand :/

Comment: If you replace `print ('Sending: ' + l)` with `label.config(text='Sending: ' + l)` you will see the updates in the label rather than the terminal. Isn't that what you were asking?

Comment: @Novel yes , but i want to see the updates in this label :
Label(Frame1, text="Commande",background='NavajoWhite2').pack(padx=165, pady=10)

how to do ? 
thank you and sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: So give that label a variable name and use the same code with the proper name. Note you have to put the `pack()` on a separate line if  you are saving the Label to a variable.

Comment: @Novel
I did what you told me , it only shows me the first line and not all the updates

Comment: I can't run your code as it is; Show me a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and I'll fix it for you.

Comment: @Novel 
 I wrote this :  `o.config(text = 'Sending:' + l).pack(padx=50, pady=50)`  with : `o= LabelFrame(moha, text= "Fase des commandes")`
 The result is that it shows me the first line  , and then there is an error message that appears
the error message is : `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'pack'`

Comment: Show me a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example and I'll fix it for you.

Comment: @Novel 


The program is longer than that, I have already mentioned what is important I can not compress more than that :(

Comment: I'm not asking you to compress it. I'm asking you to write a whole new program that I can run and that demonstrates your problem. Then I can test it and fix it and then you can apply that to your big program.

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned by Novel, in order to properly store the reference to a widget, you should separate widget **creation** from widget **alignment** (see also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43275555/4084269)).

Second, to display in **real time** the text of your label in your GUI while in a `for` loop, you will need to call `.update()` on your main window.

Below is a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows how this works:

```
import tkinter as tk
from time import sleep

def change_label():
    for i in range(5):
        label.config(text="iteration " + str(i))
        # Update the GUI in real time
        root.update()
        sleep(1)

root = tk.Tk()
# Create & align a label in 2 steps
label = tk.Label(root, text="hello") 
label.pack()

button = tk.Button(root, text="click me", command=change_label)
button.pack()

# Launch the GUI
root.mainloop()
```